# gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Tags: networking, gnupg

I want to add a new repository, But I get error at the beginning:

```
$ gpg --verbose --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

I also tried adding `hkp://` and `:80`. But did not work:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv 886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Also changed the DNS in resolv.conf to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google dns
```

It got the same error. I tried to use the `--verbose` option. But had no new debugging info.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the complete explanation, but can say this on Ubuntu 21:

Before:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Seeing that dirmngr was involved, I just launched dirmngr as root, and it did something

```
# dirmngr
dirmngr[2410562]: No ldapserver file at: '/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf'
dirmngr[2410562.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 129
dirmngr[2410562.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[2410562.0]:            trusted certificates: 129 (128,0,0,1)
dirmngr[2410562.0]: failed to open cache dir file '/root/.gnupg/crls.d/DIR.txt': No such file or directory
dirmngr[2410562.0]: creating directory '/root/.gnupg'
dirmngr[2410562.0]: creating directory '/root/.gnupg/crls.d'
dirmngr[2410562.0]: new cache dir file '/root/.gnupg/crls.d/DIR.txt' created
# Home: /root/.gnupg
# Config: [none]
OK Dirmngr 2.2.19 at your service
^C
```

After:

```
apt-key adv --verbose --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E6A233DBE3AFBEFC
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DKSIEGHESTIAa/gpg.1.sh --verbose --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E6A233DBE3AFBEFC
gpg: no running Dirmngr - starting '/usr/bin/dirmngr'
gpg: waiting for the dirmngr to come up ... (5s)
gpg: connection to dirmngr established
gpg: data source: http://162.213.33.8:11371
gpg: armor header: Comment: Hostname:
gpg: armor header: Version: Hockeypuck ~unreleased
gpg: pub  dsa1024/E6A233DBE3AFBEFC 2011-04-08  Björn Kautler <Bjoern@Kautler.net>
gpg: key E6A233DBE3AFBEFC: public key "Björn Kautler <Bjoern@Kautler.net>" imported
gpg: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg: connection to agent established
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Could it be that creating the default certificates and directories for dirmngr helped?
Best regards,
xgiannak

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217436/error-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-name) you can find the answer that really worked for me.  In a nutshell, change the key server as the old one no longer exists:

```
$ gpg --verbose --keyserver keys.openpgp.org --recv 886DDD89
```

Notice that **keys.openpgp.org** is different